# How to add sprite to a Box2d Body?

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, box2d

I just made my character for the game which is a box2d dynamic body:

```
   public Body createPlayer(){
        Body body;
        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
        def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        def.fixedRotation = true;
        def.position.set(position.x, position.y);
        body = world.createBody(def);

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(1, 1);

        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.1f;
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(this);
        body.setLinearVelocity(20, 0);
        shape.dispose();

        return(body);
    }
```

Is it possible to add texture or sprite to a body? or I'll just set the sprite position the same as the position of my body? so that it will cover the shape of the body and move like the actual box2d body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Box2D physics library is completely graphics API agnostic - It doesn't understand sprites at all.  It is a none visual (just data) simulation of a physics world.

As you mentioned, you will have to create a Sprite and move/rotate it to keep in sync with the Box2D simulation.

[Here is a good beginners guide](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/08/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-13-Physics-with-Box2D-Part-1-A-Basic-Physics-Simulations.aspx) to linking a sprite to a Box2D simulation